# Paypal Parallel Payment through Credit card PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am developing an app that requires parallel payment through credit cards with payment gateway like paypal, 
i am currently using this api.. https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-codeigniter
this api is perfectly working for paypal to paypal parallel payment but i do not know how can i integrate credit card in this api.
Please let me know if you have any answer. thanks

```
function Pay_chained()
{
    // Prepare request arrays
    $PayRequestFields = array(
                            'ActionType' => 'PAY_PRIMARY',                              // Required.  Whether the request pays the receiver or whether the request is set up to create a payment request, but not fulfill the payment until the ExecutePayment is called.  Values are:  PAY, CREATE, PAY_PRIMARY
                            'CancelURL' => site_url('paypal/adaptive_payments/pay_cancel'),                                     // Required.  The URL to which the sender's browser is redirected if the sender cancels the approval for the payment after logging in to paypal.com.  1024 char max.
                            'CurrencyCode' => 'USD',                                // Required.  3 character currency code.
                            'FeesPayer' => 'EACHRECEIVER',                                  // The payer of the fees.  Values are:  SENDER, PRIMARYRECEIVER, EACHRECEIVER, SECONDARYONLY
                            'IPNNotificationURL' => '',                         // The URL to which you want all IPN messages for this payment to be sent.  1024 char max.
                            'Memo' => '',                                       // A note associated with the payment (text, not HTML).  1000 char max
                            'Pin' => '',                                        // The sener's personal id number, which was specified when the sender signed up for the preapproval
                            'PreapprovalKey' => '',                             // The key associated with a preapproval for this payment.  The preapproval is required if this is a preapproved payment.  
                            'ReturnURL' => site_url('paypal/adaptive_payments/pay_return'),                                     // Required.  The URL to which the sener's browser is redirected after approvaing a payment on paypal.com.  1024 char max.
                            'ReverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError' => '',          // Whether to reverse paralel payments if an error occurs with a payment.  Values are:  TRUE, FALSE
                            'SenderEmail' => 'testingOcta@gmail.com',                               // Sender's email address.  127 char max.
                            'TrackingID' => ''                                  // Unique ID that you specify to track the payment.  127 char max.
                            );

    $ClientDetailsFields = array(
                            'CustomerID' => '',                                 // Your ID for the sender  127 char max.
                            'CustomerType' => '',                               // Your ID of the type of customer.  127 char max.
                            'GeoLocation' => '',                                // Sender's geographic location
                            'Model' => '',                                      // A sub-identification of the application.  127 char max.
                            'PartnerName' => ''                                 // Your organization's name or ID
                            );

    $FundingTypes = array('ECHECK', 'BALANCE', 'CREDITCARD');

    $Receivers = array();
    $Receiver = array(
                    'Amount' => '100.00',                                           // Required.  Amount to be paid to the receiver.
                    'Email' => 'waseemdildar67@gmail.com',                                              // Receiver's email address. 127 char max.
                    'InvoiceID' => '123ABCDEF',                                             // The invoice number for the payment.  127 char max.
                    'PaymentType' => 'SERVICE',                                         // Transaction type.  Values are:  GOODS, SERVICE, PERSONAL, CASHADVANCE, DIGITALGOODS
                    'PaymentSubType' => '',                                     // The transaction subtype for the payment.
                    'Phone' => array('CountryCode' => '', 'PhoneNumber' => '', 'Extension' => ''), // Receiver's phone number.   Numbers only.
                    'Primary' => 'true'                                             // Whether this receiver is the primary receiver.  Values are boolean:  TRUE, FALSE
                    );
    array_push($Receivers,$Receiver);

    $Receiver = array(
                    'Amount' => '10.00',                                            // Required.  Amount to be paid to the receiver.
                    'Email' => 'OctaTesting-buyer@gmail.com',                                               // Receiver's email address. 127 char max.
                    'InvoiceID' => '123ABCDEF',                                             // The invoice number for the payment.  127 char max.
                    'PaymentType' => 'SERVICE',                                         // Transaction type.  Values are:  GOODS, SERVICE, PERSONAL, CASHADVANCE, DIGITALGOODS
                    'PaymentSubType' => '',                                     // The transaction subtype for the payment.
                    'Phone' => array('CountryCode' => '', 'PhoneNumber' => '', 'Extension' => ''), // Receiver's phone number.   Numbers only.
                    'Primary' => 'false'                                                // Whether this receiver is the primary receiver.  Values are boolean:  TRUE, FALSE
                    );
    array_push($Receivers,$Receiver);

    $Receiver = array(
                    'Amount' => '10.00',                                            // Required.  Amount to be paid to the receiver.
                    'Email' => 'octasolutionx-facilitator@gmail.com',                                               // Receiver's email address. 127 char max.
                    'InvoiceID' => '123ABCDEF',                                             // The invoice number for the payment.  127 char max.
                    'PaymentType' => 'SERVICE',                                         // Transaction type.  Values are:  GOODS, SERVICE, PERSONAL, CASHADVANCE, DIGITALGOODS
                    'PaymentSubType' => '',                                     // The transaction subtype for the payment.
                    'Phone' => array('CountryCode' => '', 'PhoneNumber' => '', 'Extension' => ''), // Receiver's phone number.   Numbers only.
                    'Primary' => 'false'                                                // Whether this receiver is the primary receiver.  Values are boolean:  TRUE, FALSE
                    );
    array_push($Receivers,$Receiver);

    $SenderIdentifierFields = array(
                                    'UseCredentials' => ''                      // If TRUE, use credentials to identify the sender.  Default is false.
                                    );

    $AccountIdentifierFields = array(
                                    'Email' => '',                              // Sender's email address.  127 char max.
                                    'Phone' => array('CountryCode' => '', 'PhoneNumber' => '', 'Extension' => '')                               // Sender's phone number.  Numbers only.
                                    );

    $PayPalRequestData = array(
                        'PayRequestFields' => $PayRequestFields, 
                        'ClientDetailsFields' => $ClientDetailsFields, 
                        'FundingTypes' => $FundingTypes, 
                        'Receivers' => $Receivers, 
                        'SenderIdentifierFields' => $SenderIdentifierFields, 
                        'AccountIdentifierFields' => $AccountIdentifierFields
                        );  

    $PayPalResult = $this->paypal_adaptive->Pay($PayPalRequestData);

    if(!$this->paypal_adaptive->APICallSuccessful($PayPalResult['Ack']))
    {
        $errors = array('Errors'=>$PayPalResult['Errors']);
        $this->load->view('paypal/samples/error',$errors);
    }
    else
    {
        // Successful call.  Load view or whatever you need to do here.
        echo '<pre />';
        print_r($PayPalResult);
        echo '<p><a href="' . $PayPalResult['RedirectURL'] . '">PROCEED TO PAYPAL</a></p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Adaptive Payments does not support direct credit card processing.  You'll need to use Payments Pro for that, but that doesn't support a delayed chained payment like you're doing here.  People can still use credit cards, but they have to do that with Guest Checkout within the Adaptive flow, and this has limitations, so it's not always available depending on the senders / receivers involved.

Comment: Can you please suggest me any solution? i am stuck on this from the 5 days.

Comment: Adaptive Payments however can't ensure that you can use Credit Card always as a method of funding instrument, also you can't use Adaptive with PayPal Pro integration too. They are in a different set of API.